# How to save partitions to files of a specific name?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a partitioned a RDD and would like each partition to be saved to a separate file with a specific name. This is the repartitioned rdd I am working with:

```
# Repartition to # key partitions and map each row to a partition given their key rank
my_rdd = df.rdd.partitionBy(len(keys), lambda row: int(row[0]))
```

Now, I would like to saveAsTextFile() on each partition. Naturally, I should do something like

```
my_rdd.foreachPartition(lambda iterator_obj: save_all_items_to_text_fxn)
```

However, as a test, I defined save_all_items_to_text_fxn() as followed:

```
def save_all_items_to_text_fxn(iterator_obj):
     print 'Test'
```

... and I noticed that it's really only called twice instead of |partitions| number of times.

I would like to find out if I am on the wrong track. Thanks

Comment: shouldnt it just be my_rdd.foreachPartition(save_all_items_to_text_fxn)? I have no way to test it myself

Comment: You won't be able to call `saveAsTextFile` on each partition.this way.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to find out if I am on the wrong track.

Well, it looks like you are. You won't be able to call `saveAsTextFile` on a partition iterator (not mention from inside any action or transformation) so a whole idea doesn't make sense. It is not impossible to write to HDFS from Python code using external libraries but I doubt it is worth all the fuss.

Instead you can handle this using standard Spark tools:

1. An expensive way

   ```
   def filter_partition(x):
       def filter_partition_(i, iter):
           return iter if i == x else []
       return filter_partition_

   for i in rdd.getNumPartitions():
       tmp = dd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(filter_partition(i)).coalesce(1)
       tmp.saveAsTextFile('some_name_{0}'.format(i))
   ```
2. A cheap way.

   Each partition is saved to a single with a name corresponding to a partition number. It means you can simply save a whole RDD using `saveAsTextFile` and rename individual files afterwards.